# JavaScript module import with dynamic path

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following `config.js` module:

```
module.exports = {
    'x.js': '../path/to/x.js'
}
```

I would like to import `x.js` into other modules with the path defined in this config module. Is there any way to do this without importing this config module explicitly into every module that uses `x.js`?

Comment: Are you using Node.js?

Comment: No, this is a browser project